# manage login tokens (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm using Shared Preference in my flutter app and I want to manage login token.

this is my Auth class :

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _objId;

  String? _token;

  DateTime? createdAt;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String? get token {
    return _token;
  }

  String? get objId {
    return _objId;
  }
```

and it's my login method , here I tried to save login tokens in shared preferences :

```
Future<void> loginMethod(String? username, String? password) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://drbody.b4a.io/login');

    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': kParseApplicationId,
            'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': kParseRestApiKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: jsonEncode({
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
          }));

      Map<String, dynamic> jBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final jBodyData = jBody;
      if (jBody.containsKey('error')) {
        throw HttpException(jBodyData['code'].toString());
      }
      _token = jBodyData['sessionToken'];
      _objId = jBodyData['objectId'];

      // final currentData = jsonEncode({'token': _token});

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.setString('token', jBodyData['sessionToken']);

      //print(jBody);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and this is MaterialApp home page depends on authentication status, I'm using FutureBuilder to return correct page

```
 Future<bool> tryAutoLogin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? currentToken = prefs.getString('token');
    if (!prefs.containsKey('token')) {
      return false;
    }
    _token = currentToken;
    print(_token);
    notifyListeners();
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
MaterialApp(
          home: authData.isAuth
              ? TabsScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
                  future: authData.tryAutoLogin(),
                  builder: (ctx, snapshot) =>
                      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                          ? SplashScreen()
                          : AuthScreen(),
                ),)
```

but after hot restart I've got this in my console :

```
Exception caught by widgets library 
The following _CastError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
```

Comment: you haven't set the value of `authData.isAuth` anywhere so it's null

Comment: bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  } here its in my auth class

Comment: ok sry I didn't see that I think problem is you are not giving the value of shared prefs to provider. so give that value in `initState`

Comment: my main page isn't stateful so I cant use initstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this,

```
void main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var data = prefs.getString('token') ?? ''; //null check
  runApp(MyApp(token:data)); //pass it through construtor 
}
```

now you have the token and in addition just check for if string is `empty` or `null` then return false

Comment: with this approach I have token available in my app and it works fine when I do full restart but after close app and reopen it in emulator I've got null as token value and I need to full restart to get token back .

Comment: @Behnam for the first time install you will not have the token so just add a null check I have made edit to post please check it