# how to retrieve a value from shared preferences instantly? - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, save, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to show a page as an initial login, this is only displayed when my switch value is set to true.
The switch value is stored with shared preferences but when I open the application it is not recovered, only after an application update is it actually recovered. how can i get it to be recovered instantly when i open my application?

below the code:

```
Future<bool> saveSwitchState(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("switched", value);
    print('Switch Value saved $value');
    return prefs.setBool("switched", value);
  }

Future<bool> getSwitchState() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    SettingsPage.switched = prefs.getBool("switched")!;
    print(SettingsPage.switched);

    return SettingsPage.switched;
  }
```

on another page then the value that is actually recovered:

```
if(AuthPage.authenticated == false && SettingsPage.switched == true ) {
      yield ProfileNoAuth();
      return; }
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/68724144/13109948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dependency injection follow these steps :
[get it package](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

create a Separate dart containing the following code file like this:

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
Future<void> setupLocator() async {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
locator.registerLazySingleton<SharedPreferences>(() => sharedPreferences);  
}
```

call the setupLocator() method and wait for it in your main function

```
 void main() async {
    await setupLocator();
    runApp(App());
    }
```

access SharedPreferences Instance from anywhere like this:
locator();
now the SharedPreferences Instance if available anywhere in your project
please note that you dont have to wait for getting the Instance anymore, because you have only one Instance  sharable across the application

```
    bool getSwitchState() {
    final prefs = locator<SharedPreferences>();
    SettingsPage.switched = prefs.getBool("switched")!;
    print(SettingsPage.switched);

    return SettingsPage.switched;
   }
```

Comment: ok thanks, but do I have to change something in the code I wrote above? and where do I call it locator ()?

Comment: you are great ! god bless u

Comment: glad i could help <3 feel free to ask if you needed help refactoring your code

Comment: Could you possibly help me on my last question asked?

Comment: sure!! 
i just checked, did you get your answer??